# Javascript to see that div on hover or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to write a pure javascript to know that a particular div is on hover or not, if hover then variable = true else false.

```
$("#demo").hover(function(){
$(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
}, function(){
$(this).css("background-color", "black");
});
```

I tried searching in web, but I am getting only solutions based on jquery. But I want it on javascript.

```
<div id="demo">Hover on me</div>
```

Can anybody help me on this to write JavaScript same as above jquery?

Comment: Pure JS? This is with jQuery!

Comment: just select the element with the id "demo" and add event listener "mouseover" to it.
see this https://mdn.io/addEventListener

Answer (score 2):

The jQuery `.hover()` method binds two functions that are called for the `mouseover` and `mouseout` events.

If you add event listeners to those events you can replicate the behaviour.

```js
function hover(el, hoverOnCb, hoverOffCb) {
  el.addEventListener("mouseover", hoverOnCb);
  el.addEventListener("mouseout", hoverOffCb);
}

var demoElement = document.getElementById("demo");

hover(demoElement, function() {
  this.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
}, function() {
  this.style.backgroundColor = "black";
});
```

```html
<div id="demo">Hover me!</div>
```

- `this` works the same as jQuery's `$(this)`
- `this.style.backgroundColor = "black"` does the same as `$(this).css("background-color", "black")`

Comment: Thank you Sam for answering, This is what I was looking for. :)

Comment: Glad I could help! There's no obligation to do this, but if I answered your question, please consider [marking it as the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :-)

Answer (score 0):

Add event listeners to `mouseover` and `mouseout`, both of which reassign a boolean:

```js
let isHovered = false;
const demo = document.querySelector('#demo');
demo.addEventListener('mouseover', () => isHovered = true);
demo.addEventListener('mouseout', () => isHovered = false);
setInterval(() => console.log(isHovered), 200);
```

```html
<div id="demo">Hover on me</div>
```

Or, if you wanted to exactly imitate the code you posted in your question, just add a `:hover` to your CSS rules, no Javascript required:

```css
#demo {
  background-color: black;
}
#demo:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo">Hover on me</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var div = document.getElementById('demo');

div.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(){
  this.style.background = 'red';
});

div.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(){
  this.style.background = 'green';
});
```

Comment: while this may answer the question, its always better to include some text explaining things

Comment: Thank you for answering my question and it perfectly solves my issue :)